# Kind of isolated singularity for analytic function between punctured disc and annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, singularity

If $S_1:=\{z: 0<\left| z\right|<R_1 \}$ and $S_2:=\{z: r<\left| z\right|<R_2 \}$, where $r, R_1, R_2 > 0$, and $\exists f:S_1\to S_2$ such that $f$ is analytic, then what kind of an isolated singularity is $0$ of $f$?

I'd appreciate some hints, as I'm not sure how to think about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: observe that $f$ is bounded on a punctured neighborhood of zero (namely $S_1$).

Comment: Does this mean that this is a removable singularity? Another way I was thinking about this is that since $f$ is analytic everywhere on $S_1$, and since we can approach $0$ arbitrarily close, doesn't this imply that $0$ is in some neighbourhood, on which $f$ is analytic? And if so, then shouldn't $f$ be analytic at $0$ as well?

Comment: Yes, you can use Riemann's theorem on removable singularities to conclude that $0$ is removable.

Comment: Can you please clarify if $f$ is analytic on $S_1$, and $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$, then why can't $f$ be biholomorphic?

Comment: That's really a separate question rather than a clarification. The idea is as follows: (1) if $f$ is biholomorphic then $f(0)$ must lie on the boundary of $S_2$ (or else $f$ won't be injective) but on the other hand (2) since $f$ is an open map, $f(0)$ cannot be on the boundary of $S_2$.

Comment: If $f$ is not defined at $0$ ($S_1$ does not include $z=0$), then why is the fact that $f$ is not an open map on $S_1\cup \{0\}$ seem contradictory?

Comment: The key is $f$ can be extended to a holomorphic function on $S_1\cup\{0\}$, which is still an open set, so the image must also be open.

Comment: Can you please explain why $f(0)$ must lie on the boundary of $S_2$ for $f$ to be injective? Also, it's not quite clear what the fact that $f$ is not well defined on $S_2\cup \{ 0 \}$ has to do with the fact that it cannot be biholomorphic on $S_2$.

Comment: If $f(0)$ is not in the boundary, then (since $f$ is surjective) there is some $0\neq z\in S_1$ such that $f(z)=f(0)$. Choose disjoint open neighborhoods of $0$ and $z$ in $S_1$, then by the open mapping theorem the images of these neighborhoods in $S_2$ both contain the same sufficiently small disk about $f(z)=f(0)$, contradicting the fact that $f$ is injective.

Comment: If $f(0)$ is not in the boundary, then why does there have to be a $0\ne z\in S_1$ such that $f(z) = f(0)$? If $f$ is surjective, there must be a preimage of every $z\in S_2$ under $f$. But why does $0$ have to be a preimage of some point in $S_2$? Especially given that $0\not\in S_1$.

Comment: If $f(0)$ is not on the boundary, then it is in $S_2$. Since $f:S_1\to S_2$ is surjective, there is some $z\in S_1$ such that $f(z)=f(0)$.

Comment: But what if $f(z_1)=f(0)$ ($z_1\ne 0$), but since $0$ is removed, $f$ is injective on the punctured disc, but not injective on the whole disc?